# Undefined Method Error When Rendering Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rendering, partials

So, I entirely understand why one would normally receive an undefined method error, however, I am unsure why it is happening this particular time.

I have a partial:

`submissions/_submission.html.erb`

```
<div class="pure-u-1-2 rounded">
 <%= link_to submission do %>
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color: #B81324; color: #E6E6E6; margin: 10px; padding:5px;">
  <div class="clear">Project: <%= submission.project.title %></div>
  <div class="clear">Submitted By: <%= submission.submitter.username %></div>
  <div class="clear">Amount: $<%= submission.price %></div>
  <div class="clear">Description: <%= submission.description %></div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

This partial is used twice in my dashboard/index.html.erb
Once to render a collection of received submissions and again to render a collection of sent submissions:

`dashboards/index.html.erb`

```
<% if @received_submissions.length > 0 %>
 <div class="pure-u-1" id="projects"><h3 class="red">Final Tracks Received (<%= @received_submissions.length %>)</h3>
  <%= render :partial => :submission, :collection => @received_submissions %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<% if @sent_submissions.length != 0 %>
 <div class="pure-u-1" id="projects"><h3 class="red">Final Tracks Sent (<%= @sent_submissions.length %>)</h3>
  <%= render :partial => :submission, :collection => @sent_submissions %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

However, rendering the received submissions works without ailment, and rendering the sent submissions errors out with:

```
undefined method `submissions' for #<PlayerProject:0x000001052730e8>
```

Here is the dashboards_controller also, just in case:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!

 def index
  @compact = current_user.projects.where.not(status: ['Deleted','Closed']).order("id desc")
  @projects = current_user.projects.where.not(status: ['Deleted','Closed']).order("id desc")
  @received_messages = current_user.received_messages
  @received_submissions = current_user.projects.collect{|p| p.submissions }.flatten

  @player = current_user.player_projects.collect{|pp| pp.project}
  @sent_submissions = current_user.player_projects.collect{|ps| ps.submissions }.flatten
 end
end
```

`models/player_project.rb'`

```
class PlayerProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :player, :class_name => "User"
end
```

`models/submission.rb`

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :submitter, :class_name => "User"
 belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"
 belongs_to :project

 validates :amount_in_cents, :presence => true, length: { minimum: 2, :message => " must be more than $0" }
 validates :description, :presence => { :message => " cannot be blank" }
 validates :final_track_url, :presence => { :message => " Required" }

 def price
     sprintf "%.2f", (self.amount_in_cents.to_f/100.0)
 end

 def price=(val)
     self.amount_in_cents = (val.to_f*100.0).to_i
 end

 def paid?
     !!self.paypal_confirmation
 end

end
```

Comment: Do you have the `has_many :player_projects` association in your `User` model?

Comment: Yes, I actually have
`has_many :player_projects, :foreign_key => 'player_id'`

Answer (score 2):

I think your error will be model-level:

```
undefined method `submissions' for #<PlayerProject:0x000001052730e8>
```

---

**Association**

This typically suggests you don't have a particular association set up (I.E you're calling `@model.x` when `x` is not defined):

```
@sent_submissions = current_user.player_projects.collect{|ps| ps.submissions }.flatten
```

Although your `player_projects` *is* defined, I think your `submissions` attribute / association does not exist. Besides, you can use the [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method to help this: `current_user.player_projects.pluck(:submissions)`

Firstly, do you have the `submissions` attribute in your table?

Secondly, if you don't, what are you trying to achieve with it? You don't typically have a plural column in your table (denotes multiple data stores). I would use an association on a join-model

Comment: I am not sure if I am providing the information that you need...but the submission has a column for `submitter_id` which is what I actually need to compare to the current user to distinguish if it was sent by them. So maybe it needs to be a where(submission.submitter.id = current.user.id") or something of that nature?

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to cycle through the `submissions` association on the `player_projects` model?

Comment: I tried `@sent_submissions = current_user.player_projects.where(submitter_id: current_user)` I am not sure if this is getting closer perhaps?

Comment: It will be getting closer for suer - what are you trying to achieve? Just show the submissions for a particular project, for a particular user?

Comment: btw your query needs to be: `@sent_submissions = current_user.player_projects.where(submitter_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Can you post your models so I can digest them please buddy?

Comment: Everytime I answer a comment, I see I am behind by a comment. LOL -- Yes, I want to show all submissions made (to any/all projects) by that particular user, in his dashboard.

Comment: Okay thanks for this - can you post your models for us?

Comment: I just posted the submission and player project model. I have a lot of other models that are very long, but don't work into all this, do you still need them?

Comment: No these should be okay thanks! I may be a few hours as I've got to see someone in a minute, is that okay?

Comment: You're helping me out. Of course that is alright. Without the help, I would probably still be staring at it for the next few hours anyhow, lol. Thank you so much.

Comment: Haha no problem! Thank YOU for giving me a challenge!

Comment: Thank you - I will add you in about 1 / 2 hours (I've got to see someone about their newsletter - I'll take some pics for you!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= render "submission", :collection => @sent_submissions %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; It may help in the long run, at least to simplify my code, but I am still receiving the same error. Thank you still.